# Why is this .NET 6.0 async code not returning

Tags: c#, async-await, visual-studio-2022, cancellationtokensource

The following code never returns for me and I don't understand why. It gets stuck on `var s = await` and never continues. What exactly am I doing wrong? I am running this from VS2022 and it is compiled for .NET 6.0.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
cts.Token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("cancelled"));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
var s = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync().WaitAsync(cts.Token);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: Well are you hitting return in the console? Or is your point that the cancellation token isn't being observed?

Comment: Are you entering anything into the Console? `ReadLineAsync` is going to wait for user input.

Comment: Do you want to wait just 2 seconds for user-input and abort if user didn't type anything?

Comment: I can reproduce the task never completing. More than that, *even without the await operator*, the main thread blocks until you hit return in the console. I suspect that `Console.In.ReadLineAsync()` is fundamentally not quite as asynchronous as we might want it to be...

Comment: @JonSkeet can confirm.

Comment: why `Console.In.` and not just `Console.` ?

Comment: @JonSkeet My point/interest is about the cancellation token not being observed; 
@RyanWilson In any case it should stop waiting after 2 seconds when the cancellation token expires, or that is my expectation at least; @RandRandom `Console` does not have a ReadLineAsync method

Comment: FYI you should write individual comments to users, @username can only notfiy 1 user at a time, not sure if jonskeet or ryanwilson got notified, I didn't get

Comment: Even `Console.In.ReadLineAsync().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));` blocks forever.

Comment: Seems it is basically just a `TextReader` underneath the surface and doesn't support cancellation token. Looks like it will be supported in .NET 7 though.

Comment: So, who is going to write an issue on github? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/new/choose

Comment: "My point/interest is about the cancellation token not being observed" - it would have been useful to explain that in the question, along with all other relevant details, e.g. whether or not "cancelled" was printed.

Comment: @JonSkeet From the docs: "Read operations on the standard input stream execute synchronously. That is, they block until the specified read operation has completed. This is true even if an asynchronous method, such as ReadLineAsync, is called on the TextReader object returned by the In property." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.in?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Charlieface: Right. All very unfortunate :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading from the console with a timeout is surprisingly hard and `async` in Console.In is all pretend :)

You may notice that `Console.In` on Windows is `System.IO.SyncTextReader` and

`ReadLineAsync`, and even .NET7's `ReadLineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`, are not that cancellable (from [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/73374e8ee580b86204a8aafa95e4b04e948baa24/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/IO/SyncTextReader.cs#L94)):

```
public override Task<string?> ReadLineAsync()
{
   return Task.FromResult(ReadLine());
}

public override ValueTask<string?> ReadLineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   return cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested ?
      ValueTask.FromCanceled<string?>(cancellationToken) :
      new ValueTask<string?>(ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.in?view=net-6.0) on MSDN:

> "Read operations on the standard input stream execute synchronously. That is, they block until the specified read operation has completed. This is true even if an asynchronous method, such as ReadLineAsync, is called on the TextReader object returned by the In property.

So you cannot use `Console.In`. Looking at the source code, it does appear that it creates a synchronous `TextReader`.

In theory it should be possible to open an asynchronous reader using the STDIN handle, will update....

Answer (score 1):

I see that there are solid answers for the questions of ***Why is this .NET 6.0 async code not returning*** and ***what am I doing wrong*** (nothing). That being the case, I had to wonder what it would take to fulfill on the original outcome. In the process of reproducing the original issue I came up with a method that conceivably might be useful even though it doesn't directly answer the question as asked.

I would also point out that even if the original code *had* succeeded, the user only has 2 seconds to complete the *entire line*. There's no recognition of typing effort and if they miss the deadline to *ENTER* by even 1 tick then it's all gone. So this method offers the added benefit of restarting the timeout interval every time a key is pressed.

```
async Task<string> ReadLineWithTimeout(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    List<char> currentLine = new List<char>();
    var wdtStartOrRestart = DateTime.Now;

    while (true)
    {
        while (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            wdtStartOrRestart = DateTime.Now;
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
            switch (keyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    goto breakFromSwitch;
                case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                    var removeIndex = currentLine.Count - 1;
                    if(removeIndex != -1)
                    {
                        currentLine.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    // Handling these is more than we're taking on right now.
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                    currentLine.Add(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                    break;
            }
        }
        await Task.Delay(1);
        if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(wdtStartOrRestart) > timeout)
        {
            throw new TaskCanceledException();
        }
    }
    breakFromSwitch:
        return string.Join(String.Empty, currentLine);
}
```

---

**Net Core 6 Test**

```
var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await ReadLineWithTimeout(timeout) + "(ECHO)");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

[image: console output]